# Making the eyeD3-module available for import in python

Tags: python, windows, eyed3

On Windows, I have installed Python 2.7 and added *python.exe's* directory to PATH. Then I installed *pip* und used `pip install eyeD3` to install the eyeD3 module successfully. However, using `import eyeD3` doesn't work, but throws an `ImportError`.
I had the idea to adjust the `PYTHONPATH`-environment-variable in my command line, but had no clue to what I would have to set it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try `import eyed3` (without capital D)

Comment: Thanks, but it is this different on linux-platforms, since this was a popular and therefore probably working script?

Answer (score 3):

The namespace changed to eyed3 in 0.7, as did the API. On all platforms.